# Parsing Microsoft XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, docx

I have an XML file (part of a Word document) that's pretty straightforward XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties" xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes"><property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2" name="Matter"><vt:lpwstr>30738</vt:lpwstr></property><property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3" name="Document number"><vt:lpwstr>999999</vt:lpwstr></property></Properties>
```

When I parse it with SimpleXML, however, I get all of the attributes for the `<property>` items, but can't access the values (e.g., `<vt:lpwstr>999999</vt:lpwstr>`).

```
$custom = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($custom);

// Results in:
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [property] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [fmtid] => {D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}
                            [pid] => 2
                            [name] => Matter
                        )

                )
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [fmtid] => {D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}
                            [pid] => 3
                            [name] => Document number
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `print_r()` here does not print out XML nodes with a non default namespace such as `lpwstr` in your example.

But you can verify that all nodes information is available using XPath expressions. Three examples:

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $xml = <<<XML
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Properties 
        xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties" 
        xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
            <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2" name="Matter">
                <vt:lpwstr>30738</vt:lpwstr>
            </property>
            <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3" name="Document number">
                <vt:lpwstr>999999</vt:lpwstr>
            </property>
        </Properties>
    XML;
    $xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $lpwstr = $xmlobj->xpath('//vt:lpwstr');
    print_r($lpwstr);
    $lpwstr = $xmlobj->xpath('//*[local-name()="lpwstr"]');
    print_r($lpwstr);
    $lpwstr = $xmlobj->xpath('//*');
    print_r($lpwstr);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 30738
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 999999
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 30738
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 999999
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [property] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [fmtid] => {D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}
                                    [pid] => 2
                                    [name] => Matter
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [fmtid] => {D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}
                                    [pid] => 3
                                    [name] => Document number
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [fmtid] => {D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}
                    [pid] => 2
                    [name] => Matter
                )

        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 30738
        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [fmtid] => {D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}
                    [pid] => 3
                    [name] => Document number
                )

        )

    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 999999
        )

)
```

Using PHP 7.3

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I'd like to be able to programmatically explore the structure without knowing in advance what to supply to xpath(). Oddly, the 'property' elements don't seem to have any children? `foreach($custom->property as $property) { $attr = $property->attributes(); print "Property '" . $attr['name'] . "' (" . $attr['fmtid'] . "): " . $property->count() . "\n";` prints 0 for `->count()`, and `foreach($property->children() as $child)` does nothing.

Comment: Perhaps`xpath('//*')` will help out with what you mean by _programmatically explore_.